# Вывод изображения Django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь практиковаться с Django, пробую создать новости на сайте. В новостях выводится вся необходимая информация кроме изображения. Не находит картинку Not Found: /news/img/img4.png

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Articles

urlpatterns = [
   re_path(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:20],template_name='news/posts.html')),
   path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Articles, template_name="news/post.html")),
]
```

---

### posts.html

```
{% extends "mainApp/html/wrapper.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="news">Новости</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-posts">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {% for post in object_list %}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src='{{post.img}}' class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body">
                                    <a href="/news/{{post.id}}"><h3>{{post.title}}</h3></a>
                                    <h5>{{post.date|date:"D m, Y"}}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблоне используй ссылку на изображение

```
<img src='{{post.img.url}}' class="card-img-top">
```

В главный urls.py добавь

```
from django.conf import settings
...
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

При этом в settings.py у тебя должны быть настроены пути к медиа

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```